# Chef Client Run gives 'Failed to build gem native Extension' while installing tiny_tds gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, chef-infra, tiny-tds

My requirement is to use tiny_tds to connect to SQLServer Database as part of a chef client run which is running on Ubuntu OS. So, as part of this task, I have written a cookbook in which I have included the following line in the metadata.rb file:

```
gem 'tiny_tds'
```

This should install tiny_tds gem as per the chef documentation. But, I get an error saying 'Failed to build gem native Extension'. While some sites suggest on the issue being related to FreeTDS, the solutions are not clear enough to solve this issue.

Edit: Adding more info on the issue

I also tried manually installing freetds with the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get install wget
sudo apt-get install build-essential
sudo apt-get install libc6-dev
sudo wget http://www.freetds.org/files/stable/freetds-1.00.21.tar.gz
tar -xzf freetds-1.00.21.tar.gz
cd freetds-1.00.21
sudo ./configure --prefix=/usr/local --with-tdsver=7.3
sudo make
sudo make install
```

and then when I run the command

```
gem install tiny_tds
```

on the terminal, it successfully installs using native dependencies.

But the issue still exists when I do a chef client run with the command

```
sudo chef-client -o "recipe[tiny_tds_cookbook]"
```

**StackTraces:**

```
ERROR:  Error installing tiny_tds:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

current directory: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/tiny_tds-2.1.1/ext/tiny_tds
/opt/chef/embedded/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20180121-23372-1r1mxpl.rb extconf.rb
checking for sybfront.h... yes
checking for sybdb.h... yes
checking for tdsdbopen() in -lsybdb... no
checking for dbanydatecrack() in -lsybdb... no
Failed! Do you have FreeTDS 0.95.80 or higher installed?
extconf.rb failed
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to install either the compiler or the ruby development headers. We do not recommend using the gem metadata dependency system for gems that require C extensions as you would need to install the compiler before Chef starts, which is usually a thing Chef would do itself. For situations like this, the older `chef_gem` resource is generally better because you can use a cookbook like `build-essential` to install the compiler tools before installing the gem.

Comment: Even chef_gem approach gives the same error. Currently, I am working with only 1 cookbook with the chef_gem call inside my default recipe for testing purpose. Are you suggesting to have another recipe(which is included first)which uses build-essential to install the compiler tools. The native dependency in this case is with 'freetds'. Could you please provide a code example for achieving this?

Comment: You'll have to write the code yourself since the specifics depend on what exactly your gem needs installed in order to compile its extension.